# Embedding ssrs report in html page

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, reporting-services

I want to embed ssrs report web link in the html page as pdf, so I make a call to the api which uses Webclient to download bytes for the url and then on front end I create the Blob and from it object URL and embed it. This works fine when running in locally in Visual Studio, however when I publish it to Test server, the wc.DownloadData(url) errors out, internal 500. Below is the code.

Any help appreciated.

```
[Route("reports/api/getreport")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetReport([FromUri] string format, [FromUri] string reportname)
    {
        string rptserver = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServer"];
        string url = rptserver + @"/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/FolderName/" + reportname + "&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=" + format;

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        //wc.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134");
        byte[] b = wc.DownloadData(url);

        return Ok(b);
    }
```